# Can a function behave like a function *and* a context manager?

Tags: python, contextmanager

I understand how an object can be extended to be also used as a context manager. I also understand how one can easily create a context manager from a (generator) function using `contextlib`.

However, is it possible to write a function that would behave as a function when used as a function,

```
foo = make_foo()
```

and as a context manager when used as a context manager,

```
with make_foo() as foo:
  ...
```

Looking around, I would say that this is not possible -- however isn't that precisely the behavior of the `open` function? Is this behavior only possible for builtin functions, or can it also be achieved with python code?

Comment: When you write `with make_foo() as foo:`, it isn't the function itself that is the context manager, it's whatever object is returned by the function.  The only requirement is that the returned object have `__enter__()` and `__exit__()` methods.  So you couldn't return an `int` or `str` from the function and also use it as a context manager, but you could define a subclass of those types that would work.

Comment: There's nothing too magical happening in the `with` statement. After `make_foo()` returns an object (call it `obj`), `foo` is bound to `obj.__enter__()`, not `obj` itself. It's the return value of `make_foo`, not `make_foo` itself, that acts as the context manager.

Comment: Typically, the objects returned by `open` have their `__enter__` methods simply return `self`.

Comment: @user209974 ... are you asking for something like this: https://pastebin.com/39t6H9X5